# Copy From One NSArray to another when generate the Randomly images from First Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing one app in which loading images from NSMutableArray. which generate the random images and load it to the UIImageview in iOS. I want to save that array after loading as it is into Another array how may I do this. Thanks in advance.

My Code As Below.

//FrontsCards is My Array

```
    for(m=0; m<[FrontsCards count];m++)
    {
        ImgView.alpha=1;

        ImgView.tag=m;

        NSLog(@"Img View Tag %d",ImgView.tag);

        randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

        NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

        int padding=0;

        CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

        [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];

        [ImgView setAccessibilityIdentifier:[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx]];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.delegate = self;



        [self.ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];


        NSLog(@"full image name %@",fullImageName);

        NSLog(@"Image Name = %@", fullImageName);

        [self.ImgView setTag:randIdx];


        [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    }
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?.

Comment: Not Clear what you looking ? for copy one `Array` to another like `NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:FrontsCards ];`
`

Comment: Copy FrontsCards Array to New Array After genrating random number

Comment: means you need to create `Array` with objects that are randomly Generated.

Comment: yes i need to copy that randomly genaretd array to new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Another `Array` and `init` it `ViewDidLoad` and add Objects one by one as they generated.

```
NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

[yourNewArray addObject:imageName];
```

Comment: [yourNewArray count];  Display 1 everry time why this happening.

Comment: where you `init` the Array ?

Comment: k solve my issue i am new to development please support me on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet to copy an `NSMutableArray`

```
NSArray *newArray = [[oldArray mutableCopy]
```

OR:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES] autorelease];
```

Just after this code : 
        `randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];`

save the index into another array and use it to point to the original array .

Comment: i get the randomly genrated Array.